# Exact definitions of past and future null infinity for a generic spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

The definition of the asymptotic flatness is motivated by the conformal compactification of various space-time geometry, including the 3+1D Minkowski, the Kruskal spacetime, and the Rindler spacetime.

In all of such examples, one can finally arrives at a metric such that the null geodesic that light-rays coming from the past infinity or going towards the future time infinity could be straightened out.

This then defines the $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$, the future and the past null infinity.

This motivates well the definition of the asymptotic flatness as in Prof. Harvey Reall's Part III black holes lecture notes since it assumes that such $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$ exists in generic spacetime as this notion enters in the definition in pp 67.

The question is two-fold.

1. How to define $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$ for a generic spacetime?
2. Is the "straightened out" process as in the Penrose's diagrams necessary? For example, I can perform one extra step of coordinate transformation in all such conformal compactifications such that $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$ is curved. How can one really prove that there always exists a coordinate transformation such that $\mathcal{I}^{\pm}$ would be $45$ degree lines in my Carter-Penrose diagrams for generic spacetime? Are there counter examples?

Comment: ”generic spacetime” need not have a null infinity. For example conformal boundary of AdS space is timelike. Or do you mean “generic asymptotically flat” spacetime?

Comment: Sorry. Indeed, there is also a concept called asymptomatically AdS. But if you use the word “generic asymptotically flat” then you have to define it. But you then have to use past and future null infinity, which leads to circular definition.

Comment: There is no circularity. There is a single concept: “asymptotically flat at null infinity” that does not rely on preexisting definition of scri but rather scri appears as a part of that concept's definition.

Comment: Thanks for your further explanation. If "scri appears as a part of that concept's definition", could you please give the full definition of "asymptotically flat at null infinity"?

Comment: Sure, for example in Ashtekar's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1800), p. 3.

Comment: Indeed the Definition 1 of Ashtekar's paper does not require a pre-defined $\mathcal{I}$. But in p. 4, it says "These conditions immediately imply that $\mathcal{I}$ is necessarily a null, 3-dimensional manifold." Why must $\mathcal{I}$ be null? I could not quite follow the flow the argumentation there.

Comment: At a glance I suggest using the Einstein equations in physical spacetime and transformation law of Ricci tensor under conformal rescaling.

Comment: The null infinity simply is the spatial and temporal infinities together (if such regions exist in a particular spacetime). The shape of the diagram is an artifact of compactification and has no physical meaning. It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish in your question.